# Rules for filtering spam that comes written in russian alphabet, Mail 4.5, OS 10.6.8

Tags: mail.app, spam

I receive almost 99.99% e-mail spam in Russian.
I'm not sure why, but it makes it really easy for me to tell spam apart from real mail.

I use Apple mail 4.5 on MacOS 10.6.8, and I'd like to make a rule that somehow catches mails written mainly in Russian and marks them as junk.

So far I made rules that catch individual russian letters, but is there a more generic and efficient way of filtering it?

Actually I don't read Russian and don't receive any real e-mail in Russian.

Answer (score -1):

[From MacHints](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030423092620418):

- Select Mail -> Preferences -> Rules
- Select Junk -> Edit
- Select (+) to add a new rule.
- Click on the "From" drop-down and select "Edit Header List..."
- Add "Content-Class" by typing "Content-Class" in the "Header:" text box and then hit "Add Header" and "OK."
- Set the first pop-up on your new rule to Content-Class, the second to Contains, and the third to charset="windows-1251".
- Select (+) to add a new rule.
- Set the pop-ups to Subject, Contains, and charset="windows-1251".
- Select (+) to add a new rule.
- Set the pop-ups to From, Contains, and charset="windows-1251".
- Click the "OK" button to end the rule definition.

Comment: Please consider providing your links in context, as other webpages are always subject to change and may not benefit future visitors.